# Filter pyspark dataframe based on time difference between two columns

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, two of which are of type `pyspark.sql.TimestampType`. I would like to filter this dataframe to rows where the time difference between these two columns is less than one hour.

I'm currently trying to do this like so:

`examples = data.filter((data.tstamp - data.date) < datetime.timedelta(hours=1))`

But this fails with the following error message:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`tstamp` - `date`)' due to data type mismatch: '(`tstamp` - `date`)' requires (numeric or calendarinterval) type, not timestamp
```

What is the correct method to achieve this filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns have different types, it's difficult to interpret what the difference means, usually for timestamps it's seconds and for dates it's days. You can transform both columns to unix timestamps beforehand to get a difference in seconds:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
data.filter(
    psf.abs(psf.unix_timestamp(data.tstamp) - psf.unix_timestamp(data.date)) < 3600
)
```

**EDIT**

This function will work on strings (given they have a correct format), on timestamps and on dates:

```py
import datetime
data = hc.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([[datetime.datetime(2017,1,2,1,1,1), datetime.date(2017,8,7)]]), ['tstamp', 'date'])
data.printSchema()
    root
     |-- tstamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- date: date (nullable = true)

data.select(
    psf.unix_timestamp(data.tstamp).alias('tstamp'), psf.unix_timestamp(data.date).alias("date")
).show()
    +----------+----------+
    |    tstamp|      date|
    +----------+----------+
    |1483315261|1502056800|
    +----------+----------+
```

Comment: The columns are not different types, but instead both are type `pyspark.sql.TimestampType`

Comment: Additionally, these are datetime objects, so the `unix_timestamp` function will not work, since it operates on string input. I guess I could convert them from datetimes to strings then run them through `unix_timestamp`. I wonder if there is a more straightforward way though.

Comment: In pyspark we don't have access to all the datetime functions from python, the only other function for time differences is datediff for days. So unless you write a UDF which will be less efficient than a straight pyspark solution you'll have to use a timestamp difference by converting them into `int`.

Comment: Unfortunately that solution does not work. Although no error is thrown, the resultant rows contain records where the difference between the columns is much longer than an hour.

Comment: Actually, it might work if I reverse the order of the columns in the subtraction operation. Let me double check...

Comment: Yes, it will work if I reverse the order or just use the `pyspark.sql.abs` function. Thank you.

Comment: You are right, I didn't account for negative time differences. Please provide a full reproducible example next time.