# Filter pyspark by time difference

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe in pyspark that looks like this:

```
+----------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------+
|Session_Id|Instance_Id        |Actions|Start_Date             |End_Date               |Duration|
+----------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------+
|14252203  |i-051fc2d21fbe001e3|2      |2019-12-17 01:07:30.000|2019-12-17 01:07:30.000|0       |
|43024091  |i-051fc2d21fbe001e3|2      |2019-12-17 01:08:00.000|2019-12-17 01:08:00.000|0       |
|50961995  |i-0c733c7e356bc1615|2      |2019-12-17 01:07:30.000|2019-12-17 01:07:30.000|0       |
|56308963  |i-0c733c7e356bc1615|2      |2019-12-17 01:08:00.000|2019-12-17 01:08:00.000|0       |
|60120472  |i-0c733c7e356bc1615|2      |2019-12-17 01:07:30.000|2019-12-17 01:07:30.000|0       |
|69132492  |i-051fc2d21fbe001e3|2      |2019-12-17 01:07:30.000|2019-12-17 01:07:30.000|0       |
+----------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------+
```

I'm trying to filter any rows that are too recent with this:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()

filtered = grouped.filter(f.abs(f.unix_timestamp(now) - f.unix_timestamp(datetime.datetime.strptime(f.col('End_Date')[:-4], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))) > 100)
```

which transforms `End_Date` to a timestamp and calculates the difference from now till `End_Date` and filters anything less than 100 seconds. Which I got from [Filter pyspark dataframe based on time difference between two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849311/filter-pyspark-dataframe-based-on-time-difference-between-two-columns)

Every time I run this, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 2019-12-19 18:55:13.268489 of type <type 'datetime.datetime'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

How can I filter by comparing timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing between Python functions and Spark. `unix_timestamp` function requires a string or Column object but you're passing a Python datetime object, that why you get that error.

Instead use Spark builtin functions : `current_date` which gives you column with current date value and `to_date` to convert `End_Date` column to date.

This should work fine for you:

```
filtered = grouped.filter(abs(unix_timestamp(current_date()) - unix_timestamp(to_date(col('End_Date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))) > 100)
```